# How to get color values for outlook themes using outlook plugin

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, addin-express

is there way to get outlook theme colors for items such as selected mail item color, text color, background color .. etc using outlook plugin and c#.?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only the themes for all Office applications are available, not the specific UI implementations for each theme (e.g. selections, text, backgrounds, etc.).  You could take screenshots and use color pickers in image editing applications to determine the colors of individual elements.

Otherwise the specific theme can be read in the registry in the "UI Theme" key at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common (e.g. 0 = "Colorful", 4 = "Black", etc.).